# What should I call the operation that limits a string's length?

Tags: string, language-agnostic, naming-conventions, terminology

This is a language-agnostic question - unless you count English as a language.

I've got this list of items which can have very long names.

For aesthetic purposes, these names must be made shorter in some cases, adding dots (...) to indicate that the name is longer. So for example, if article.name returns this:

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I'd like to get this other output.

```
lorem ipsum dolor ...
```

I can program this quite easily. My question is: how should I call that shortening operation? I mean the name, not the implementation. Is there a standard English name for it?

Comment: Perhaps just truncate with an [optional parameter](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/truncate)?

Comment: Indeed. That was my preferred solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Truncation, or soft truncation (because of the ellipsis)

I would call the function `truncate`, and that seems to be the consensus.

CPAN: http://metacpan.org/pod/String::Truncate
MooTools: https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/670-new-addition-stringtruncate-method
Prototype: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/truncate
Smarty: http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.modifier.truncate.php
Jinja: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#truncate

Comment: I received lots of very valid responses. I'm choosing this one because it happens to be called like that on the library I'm using (rails). This comment helped me find it. I also like it a bit more than ellipsize, although I realize it is a completely personal choice.

Answer (score 15):

### Use 'ellipsize'

UserlandFrontier calls such a method ellipsize:

http://docserver.userland.com/string/ellipsize

So does Android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html

and many others (see google)

Comment: The name ellipsize seems a bit obscure to me. Pretty much everyone will know what truncate means

Comment: I agree that everybody knows what truncate is, but I think that is exactly the problem: truncate implies that the string is cut of and not that it is shortened and an ellipsis added.

Comment: I like ellipsize, and hope that it catches on as a "standard" name for this function. Truncate is a bit generic.

Comment: To me it implies the addition of an ellipsis. Maybe a hybrid is in order?

Comment: You know, they say you shouldn't verbalize nouns ;->

Comment: @Thomas - Maybe if the English language made sense maybe more people would follow the rules. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I prefer truncate however. "ellipsize", while appropiate, is not real English, but "English-ish". Nothing wrong with that, but not exactly what I was looking for. But +1 because if I see ellipsize in the future I will probably know what it means.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a huge fan of creating new words for function names. I'd be inclined to use actual words and call the function `TruncateWithEllipsis` or something abundantly clear.

Comment: Same here, something like `'lorem impsum dolor'.truncateWith('...')` sounds good to me

Comment: @Infinity - That would go perfect with a c# extension method. Of course it might be annoying to have to specify every time.

Comment: This was a bit too long for my taste, but your code will probably be more readable than mine for stranger eyes. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

> **truncate**: To shorten  something as if by cutting off part of it.

[Source](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truncate)

Answer (score 1):

Although less explicit than Thomas' `TruncateWithEllipsis`, I might name it `abbreviate` *because* I may want to abbreviate things differently in the future, or depending on context, or what the thing I'm abbreviating is.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, I'm not planning to change this functionality in the future, so the truncate name sounds a bit more appropiate.

Comment: IMO, abbreviate would mean transforming "In My Opinion" to "IMO"

Comment: @Don, "abbr" is the most common abbreviation for "abbreviation". An initialism is, indeed, *one form* of abbreviation; truncation is another form of abbreviation.